# Location issue with Dataset file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xsd, dataset

I have created a dataset using Visual Studio, however when trying to access it from a class meant to be my Business Logic Layer, I can't. It is simply not visible. In addition, if the dataset is placed in a folder I get tens of errors in its designer file, that don't appear in the root location.

I'm sure its a stupid small mistake in some property or a missing reference but for the life of me I can't find it. Has anyone had this issue before or know of a way to fix it?

I should mention in addition that the folder I am placing the dataset in is within the App_Code folder

Comment: can you post code for BLL and PL methods. It might be problem with class type.. make sure the class is accessible i.e. making it public.

Comment: BLL is declared as public. Not sure what you mean by PL, but the .XSD file of the dataset has the modifier set as public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not positive of the issue, I think it was incorrect ordering in the web.config file. I removed the  tag area, and moved around some standard files, cleant, rebuilt, and it worked.